# sysmail_mailitems in msdb and signalr not working

Tags: sql, signalr, broker

Is it possible to get an insert into `sysmail_mailitems` to update a web page via `signalr`? I have this working with another table, and my own insert sproc, but when firing a db mail email, the subsequent insert into `sysmail_mailitems` does not fire a record in my web page via `signalr`. I have run

```
ALTER DATABASE msdb SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement must not reference system tables or views, including catalog views and dynamic management views.  see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx